# Reattempting unsuccessful call to JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

The idea is to try calling JNI_CreateJavaVM  with a large heap memory parameter, and, if that fails, call it again with the heap memory parameter omitted so a default is used instead.

A failure on the first call gives me a return code of JNI_ENOMEM (not enough memory), which is what I have anticpiated.

However, it seems that a subsequent call to JNI_CreateJavaVM fails with a return code of -1 (JNI_ERR: unknown error).

Is there some kind of reset I have to perform before I retry? Needless to say, my subsequent call on its own is successful.

I'm tagging this C and C++ as the methods of accessing the interfaces are identical in these languages.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with JDK 11 (neither OpenJDK nor Oracle JDK). When I call `JNI_CreateJavaVM` with a too large heap size, the whole process crashes before the return code of `JNI_CreateJavaVM` can be evaluated. Applying a `catch` block also does not work. It seems the question might no longer be applicable to current JDK versions.